# Cumulative count of different strings in a column based on value of another column

Tags: pandas

I've got a df that looks like this with duplicate ID's

```
     ID    Usage_type
0     5    Note
1     6    Note
2     7    Service
3     5    Note
4     7    Note
5     10   Service
```

I want an extra two columns that indicate the cumulative count of usage_type for each ID like so:

```
     ID    Usage_type   type_Note    type_Service
0     5    Note         1            0
1     6    Note         1            0
2     7    Service      0            1
3     5    Note         2            0
4     7    Note         1            1
5     10   Service      0            1
```

I've used cumulative count to get the total count of Usage_type for each ID but want to break it down further into separate counts for each string.

Screenshot below shows what the current counts for an example ID
[image]

Comment: Can you explain please why in the ```index``` 4 you have 1 in ```type_Service``` ? I understand why have 1 in ```type_Note``` there, but why for ```type_Service```?

Comment: @sophocles At index 2 there is a record for ```Service``` for ID 7. ID 7 then appears again at index 4 as a ```Note``` so the cumulative count for ID 7 is 1 for ```Note``` and also 1 for ```Service```

Answer (score 2):

You could filter your dataframe on the different Usage_type with [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and perform a grouped cumulative count. Lastly, a grouped [`ffill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.ffill.html) will account for the cases you explained to me in the comments:

```
grp_cc = df.groupby([*df]).cumcount()+1 
df.loc[df.Usage_type=='Note','type_Note'] = grp_cc
df.loc[df.Usage_type=='Service','type_Service'] = grp_cc
```

This will get you:

```
   ID Usage_type  type_Note  type_Service
0   5       Note        1.0           NaN
1   6       Note        1.0           NaN
2   7    Service        NaN           1.0
3   5       Note        2.0           NaN
4   7       Note        2.0           NaN
5  10    Service        NaN           1.0
```

And then performing a grouped forward fill and filling in the null values get's you what you need:

```
df = df.groupby('ID').ffill().fillna(0)    

>>> df    
 
   Usage_type  type_Note  type_Service
0       Note        1.0           0.0
1       Note        1.0           0.0
2    Service        0.0           1.0
3       Note        2.0           0.0
4       Note        1.0           1.0
5    Service        0.0           1.0
```

Comment: I think the solution in your edit is slightly off. Index 4 should be 1.0 for ```type_Note``` and 1.0 for ```type_Service```. Is there a workaround for that? Other than that its exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: Yes apologies for the mistake, I just updated my answer and now we get the correct result.

Comment: I tried the new solution but still get an incorrect count. Posted a screenshot above showing what it looks like for 1 ID. The fourth row should have type_Note = 1 and Type_Service = 3. The fifth row should have type_Note = 1 and Type_Service = 4

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to your problem, and solved it by creating a custom function here's the bit of code that worked for me:

```
def truefalse(df):
    count=0
    df_2=pd.DataFrame({'col':[0]*(len(df))})
    for i in range(len(df)):
        if df[i] == True:
            df_2['col'][i]=count+1
            count+=1
    return df_2
ID=[5,6,7,5,7,10]
usg=['Note','Note','Service','Note','Note','Service']
df=pd.DataFrame({'ID':ID,'Usage_type':usg})
for unid in df['ID'].unique():
     df['type_Note'] = truefalse(((df['Usage_type'] =='Note') & ( df['ID'] ==unid)))['col']+df['type_Note']
     df['type_Service'] = truefalse(((df['Usage_type'] =='Service) & ( df['ID'] ==unid)))['col']+df['type_Note']
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there a way to implement that on the original dataframe (i.e. just adding two extra columns at the end)?

Comment: Well the code I showed adds 1 column to the original dataframe if you want to do it for both just do it like this:. 
for unid in df['ID'].unique():
     df['type_Note'] = truefalse(((df['Usage_type'] =='Note') & ( df['ID'] ==unid)))['col']+df['type_Note'].                 
                           df['type_Service'] = truefalse(((df['Usage_type'] =='Service) & ( df['ID'] ==unid)))['col']+df['type_Note']